# Why is null Unity Object equal to null in specialized class but not equal to null in generic class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object, null, equality

Attach TestMono to an empty GameObject, leave the serialized field uov empty and play. The result is not what I expected.

```cs
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Object = UnityEngine.Object;

namespace TestMisc.Scripts
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Variable<T>
    {
        [SerializeField] T m_Value;

        public T Value => m_Value;

        public void LogInsideGenericClass()
        {
// Result: Inside generic class: equal to null: False    equal to default: True
            Debug.Log($"Inside generic class: equal to null: {Value == null}    equal to default: {Value as Object == default}");
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class UnityObjectVariable : Variable<Object>
    {
        public void LogInsideSpecializedClass()
        {
// Result: Inside specialized class: equal to null: True    equal to default: True
            Debug.Log($"Inside specialized class: equal to null: {Value == null}    equal to default: {Value as Object == default}");
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using UnityEngine;

namespace TestMisc.Scripts
{
    public class TestMono : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] UnityObjectVariable uov;

        void Start()
        {
            uov.LogInsideGenericClass();
            uov.LogInsideSpecializedClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Why null Unity Object is not equal to null inside generic class?

Answer (score 0):

Unity override the `==` operator for Unity objects to make them equal to null in cases where the object isn't actually null (for example if it has been destroyed). Operators are not polymorphic; if you cast the object to `Object` then compare it with `==` it will use `Object`'s `==` operator, not some "override" from an inheriting class.

If you compare using `Equals` it should yield the same result with or without a cast.

If you only want to check for truly null references, use `ReferenceEquals`.

Answer (score 0):

In general see [Unity custom == operator](https://blog.unity.com/engine-platform/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it)

=> it's a bit more complex.

Your generic `==` happens on a c# `System.Object` level - where a serialzed field in Unity is always initialized - just with an invalid `UnityEngine.Object` instance.

On the other side `UnityEngine.Object ==` is in the end a pointer into the underlying `c++` engine where those instances are actually living and maintained.

See [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs#L616)

> ```
> public static bool operator==(Object x, Object y) { return CompareBaseObjects(x, y); }
>
> static bool CompareBaseObjects(UnityEngine.Object lhs, UnityEngine.Object rhs)
> {
>     bool lhsNull = ((object)lhs) == null;
>     bool rhsNull = ((object)rhs) == null;
>
>     if (rhsNull && lhsNull) return true;
>
>     if (rhsNull) return !IsNativeObjectAlive(lhs);
>     if (lhsNull) return !IsNativeObjectAlive(rhs);
>
>     return lhs.m_InstanceID == rhs.m_InstanceID;
> }
>
> static bool IsNativeObjectAlive(UnityEngine.Object o)
> {
>     if (o.GetCachedPtr() != IntPtr.Zero)
>         return true;
>
>     //Ressurection of assets is complicated.
>     //For almost all cases, if you have a c# wrapper for an asset like a material,
>     //if the material gets moved, or deleted, and later placed back, the persistentmanager
>     //will ensure it will come back with the same instanceid.
>     //in this case, we want the old c# wrapper to still "work".
>     //we only support this behaviour in the editor, even though there
>     //are some cases in the player where this could happen too. (when unloading things from assetbundles)
>     //supporting this makes all operator== slow though, so we decided to not support it in the player.
>     //
>     //we have an exception for assets that "are" a c# object, like a MonoBehaviour in a prefab, and a ScriptableObject.
>     //in this case, the asset "is" the c# object,  and you cannot actually pretend
>     //the old wrapper points to the new c# object. this is why we make an exception in the operator==
>     //for this case. If we had a c# wrapper to a persistent monobehaviour, and that one gets
>     //destroyed, and placed back with the same instanceID,  we still will say that the old
>     //c# object is null.
>     if (o is MonoBehaviour || o is ScriptableObject)
>         return false;
>     
>      return DoesObjectWithInstanceIDExist(o.GetInstanceID());
>  }
>
>  [NativeMethod(Name = "UnityEngineObjectBindings::DoesObjectWithInstanceIDExist", IsFreeFunction = true, IsThreadSafe = true)]
>  internal extern static bool DoesObjectWithInstanceIDExist(int instanceID);
> ```